# Can't move or resize windows - fluxbox

Tags: linux, opensuse, window-manager, fluxbox

I recently uninstall fedora on my laptop and installed opensuse instead.
Everything was working fine.

Since I used fluxbox with fedora and I still use it with opensuse, I decided to use my old configuration of fluxbox and I modify some files (don't remember exactly which, that's the problem).
The problem is that now I can't move or resize my windows anymore (for now i use the alt key + my mouse but it is a little bit anoying).

Did someone had the same problem or/and know where correct it.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

These lines in ~/.fluxbox/keys are used for moving windows with the title bar and corners:

```
  # Normal window movement.
  OnTitlebar Move1 :StartMoving 
  OnLeftGrip Move1 :StartResizing bottomleft 
  OnRightGrip Move1 :StartResizing bottomright 
  OnWindowBorder Move1 :StartMoving
```

I usually hold the alt-key and drag with the left mouse button to move a window, and drag with the right mouse button to resize.  This allows me to use very small right & left grips.  It can be done by adding these lines to the keys file:

```
  # alt + left/right click to move/resize a window
  OnWindow Mod1 Mouse1 :MacroCmd {Raise} {Focus} {StartMoving}
  OnWindow Mod1 Mouse3 :MacroCmd {Raise} {Focus} {StartResizing NearestCorner}
```

Comment: correct answer.